# How to export Java Web Service using Netbeans 8.0?

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, glassfish, jax-ws

I am learning how to create a Java Web Service JAX-WS. To achieve this I followed this Netbeans 8.0 guide:

- https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html

In the guide we learn how to create a Web Server, and a Client. Before running the server, I deploy it to NetBeans GlassFish server, and then the client access it. Everything works well locally.

However, now I wish to export the web server into an external file (war, jar, etc) and to run it on a remote machine, so I can then try to access it using my local client.

I have tried using "right-click" on project and searched for export options, but I found none. In the File menu, I am only allowed to export to a ZIP file, which is not what I want because I want to be able to run my code on a remote server that has no NetBeans and no GlassFish installed.

How do I do this?

---

**EDIT**

I wish to launch this without maven or any other tools of the kind.

After reading a completely unrelated article from Oracle for Java EE7 I found that i can create wars build building and cleaning the project (following is the version of that article for Java EE6, because I cannot find the one for EE7 :S ):

- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html

Having this in mind the challenge is now to launch the generated `.war` file using `java -jar something.jar`. For this purpose I am considering using Jetty 8.

Comment: Did it create a WAR file, when you build the project? Do you want to deploy the WAR manually or by script? Are you using Maven?

Comment: It created a WAR when I click in "Build and Clean". I do not use Maven, at this point I want to launch it manually by using `java -jar jarName` or something similar. I am using jetty for that now, I hope it works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to deploy your WAR file to the application server/ web container you want it to run your application.

E.g. for Jetty a quick search for "jetty war deploy" should give you links such as:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications

Comment: Alright thanks!! 
Now, I have questions about the client. Should I create a separate thread?

And why is my question marked with -1? =(

Comment: Yes, start a new question. Provide all necessary information to avoid down votes.

Comment: Basically the question I asked (the question was unclear) and some basic research efforts were not shown.

Comment: So, I was supposed to say I was not using "Maven" even though I had never heard of it before? Also, how is reading an entire tutorial, performing a Stack-overflow search (you cannot make a question without making a search, in case you do not know) qualify as *no research efforts*? Are you people always this rude? Ever heard of the famous *benefit of doubt*? The way I see it, someone was not fair.

Comment: Rude? I did help you to solve your problem and how to avoid down votes in the future. Thy system didn't allow me to undo the down vote once you provided the necessary information to make the question clear. The link you provided mentioned Maven. You wrote about "deploy" and "war" as well. A Stackoverflow search is necessary but not enough, I'm afraid. Please also search the internet. It's what we all have to do as you've seen in my answer. In short always ask yourself if you have provided as much information as you can so people can help you quickly. I'm sorry if this came off as rude.

Comment: The link mentions it, but only as a side-note/off-track way of building the project. I can also mention space unicorns. Does it mean you know what they are for? Do you even pay attention to space unicorns if you are trying to build a plane? Yes, it looks rude because it messes my reputation. Furthermore you assume too much without even giving the benefit of doubt. And if you want to get critical about "help", perhaps I should remind you that my comment about Jetty was done **before** your answer? So yes, it was rude - and I still gave you kudos++.

Comment: If it means so much to you, please update your question with the info you've given in your comment. I think the system will then allow me to undo the down-vote (which happened before your comment as far as I remember) and it would be OK for me as the question is clear now.

Comment: Yes, it means something to me. Not all users have 12K kudos. I have edited the question with more of my research. Hope it it clear now.